# I'm trying to load a collectionView in a TableViewController and adding the collectionView in the subView of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This is the complete code which configures the tableView controller.

```
class SearchViewControllerTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var users = [User]()
var filteredUsers = [User]()
var searchBar = UISearchBar()
var inSearchMode = false
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var collectionViewEnabled = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(SearchUserCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reusableIdentifier)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    configureSearchBar()
    configureCollectionView()
    fetchUsers()
    print("Collection View \(collectionView.isHidden)")
}
```

This is the code for configuring collectionView.

```
func configureCollectionView() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)! - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.register(SearchPostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reusableIdentifierCollectionView)
}
```

This is code for tableView. Which loads up some users in the app.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if inSearchMode {
        return filteredUsers.count
    } else {
        return users.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reusableIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SearchUserCellTableViewCell
    var user: User!
    if inSearchMode {
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        user = users[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.user = user
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 69
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var user: User!
    if inSearchMode {
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        user = users[indexPath.row]
    }
    
    // Instance for user profile VC
    let userProfileView = UserProfileCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    
    // Assign the selected user.
    userProfileView.user = user
    
    // Navigate to the selected user's profile
    navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfileView, animated: true)
    userProfileView.setNavigationBar()
}
```

This is the code for collectionView dataSource and delegate.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (view.frame.width - 2) / 3
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 15
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reusableIdentifierCollectionView, for: indexPath) as! SearchPostCell
    return cell
}
```

On top of the tableView I want to add a CollectionView which should be hidden by default.

But the collectionView is not showing up. But on loading up the view "collectionView.isHidden" returns false

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to add subviews directly to table views or collection views.

This line: `tableView.addSubview(collectionView)` won't work.

Further, UITableViewController and UICollectionViewController are very specialized view controllers that will only manage a table view/collection view. You can't add other subviews to those view controller classes.